# Javascript recursion problems

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am wanting to return the index of a string in a given array (or -1 if not present) only using recursion and no looping, but am running into some issues. Below is my code:

```js
function findIndex(arr, val, idx = 0){
  if (arr[0] === val){
    return idx
  } 
  else if (arr[0] !== val) {
    arr.splice(0,1);
    idx +=1;
    findIndex(arr, val, idx)
  } 
  else { 
    return -1
  }
}

let animals = ["duck", "cat", "pony"];

// findIndex(animals, "cat");  // 1
// findIndex(animals, "porcupine");   // -1
```

The `findIndex(animals, "cat");` should return 1, however nothing appears in the console after running. Also I receive  a Stack Overflow error when I run `findIndex(animals, "porcupine");` when it is supposed to return -1. I can't think of what is going on wrong

Comment: You do not return, common beginner problem with recursion. `return findIndex(arr, val, idx)`

Comment: You should check whether `arr.length` is 0 (*before* comparing the `arr[0]` value), and return `-1` in that case.

Comment: you need to check if you've reached the end of the array. You'll never hit that last else because you've covered all cases already with the first two if statements

Comment: `findIndex(arr, val, idx)` should be `return findIndex(arr, val, idx)`

Comment: Thank you @Nick and @EricHB. After adding return to when findIndex is called and using the `if (arr.length === 0)`, the code works great!

Comment: @anUp_and-comer good to hear. I'm glad we could help.